# How to determine Oracle Fusion Middleware version

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, scripting, oracle-fusion-middleware

I want to know which version of OFMW is installed. I know that there is information stored in $OFMW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/.product.properties: WLS_PRODUCT_VERSION=10.3.3.0

But what if Oracle update Weblogic to 10.4?

And what about other products in Fusion Middleware?

If it is not stored in a property file, is there a class, that I can run to get that information?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to play with "opatch" command: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e16793/opatch.htm.

It is installed with Oracle Fusion Middleware products inside `<ORACLE_HOME>/Opatch` or `<MIDDLEWARE_HOME>/oracle_common/OPatch` directories and I found the following simple options to find installed products and versions.

- List all the Oracle Homes and the Oracle Toplevel Component

  ```
  opatch lshomes
  ```
- Display the version of the Oracle Toplevel Component

  ```
  opatch lsinventory -all
  ```
- List the components versions of the specified Oracle Home:

  ```
  opatch lsinventory -all -oh <ORACLE_HOME>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

you should read and use this document :

```
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/core.1111/e10105/release.htm#ASADM10165
```

Answer (score -1):

You try navigating to Oracle Home/inventory/Components*?

[Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/core.1111/e10105/release.htm#i635005)